# Android: Is it common to have the Account Settings section incorporated into Settings?

Tags: android

I am designing an Android app and need to decide where to place the Account Settings section (that is, the place where the user can update his profile details, change password, etc.) - I currently have a Settings section accessible via an action overflow button at the rightmost side of the main action bar. And I'm thinking to incorporate the Account Settings section into it as well. So, the Account Settings could either be another item in the action overflow menu, or incorporated into the Settings section itself. Is it a common pattern in Android apps?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Googles Android Apps as an example they integrate their settings into multiple levels EG top level Settings select: 'Settings' -> lists: "General Settings, Account Settings (xxx@gmail.com), About".

More info on Android design patterns for settings:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html

Answer (score 2):

As you are creating a custom app ,Account setting can be placed in the menu itself .It helps user to access the account setting at any time with few taps .